# camel restlet component url matching

Tags: apache-camel, restlet, url-mapping

I have the following camel route

```
<camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="restlet:/foo/{bar}/model" />
        <camel:process ref="dummyProcessor" />
</camel:route>
```

My problem is why do I have match for these requests (basically I can put anything after model)

> GET /foo/hoi/modelbroken
>
> GET /foo/hoi/modelwhyisthisamatch

I expect that these should return 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Matching Mode configuration option in Restlet.

http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.3/core/routing/

While guide says it should be MODE_EQUALS by default, looks like it's Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH if you check the code:

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/engine/component/InternalRouter.java

Not sure if it's a bug in guide or source, but you can configure it for yourself.

Comment: Great, thanks. Now the question is how to configure the restlet component in camel to use Template.MODE_EQUALS?

Comment: @ZoltanAltfatter I don't see it in the options list and since Camel hides the component internals from you, I believe your only options are to fork the component, add a "matchingMode" param & send a patch.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered something similar, and update to Java 11 and camel solved this issue.